# InvalidOperationException: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

This happens after I customized the asp.net core identity services to support multi-tenancy based on [This article](https://github.com/Avareto/Asp.Net-Core-Identity-Multitenancy/tree/master/AspNetCoreMultitenancy/Models). I simplified it to suite my needs.

Here is my basic setup.

1) Custom application user

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEntityBase{}
```

2) Custom Role

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>, IEntityBase{}
```

3) Custom Role store

```
public class RoleStoreMultiTenant<TRole> : RoleStore<TRole, ApplicationDbContext, int>{}
```

4) Custom User Store

```
public class UserStoreMultiTenant<TUser, TRole, TKey> : UserStore<TUser, TRole, ApplicationDbContext, int>{}
```

5) My role service inheriting from above (3). This is just to separate my code from RoleStore overridden code.

```
public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStoreMultiTenant<ApplicationRole>{}
```

6) My User service inheriting from above (4). This is just to separate my code from UserStore overridden code.

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStoreMultiTenant<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>{}
```

7) My ApplicationDbContext is;

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>{}
```

8) My startup configurations related to identity (in ConfigureServices).

```
services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
services.AddScoped<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserStore>();
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(o =>
{
o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
//options code
}).AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>();
```

9) In Startup Configure method I have;

```
//other code
app.UseIdentity();
//other code
```

10) I have a basecontroller expecting below via the constructor injection

```
public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, 
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    IMessageServices messageServices, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    AppTenant currentTenant, IMapper mapper)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _messageServices = messageServices;
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BaseController>();
    _currentTenant = currentTenant;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

All other controllers are inheriting from this base.

My Database migrations works fine and identity db structures getting created with my custom properties without any issues. However when I run the application I get the error shown in the topic. Which is;

```
InvalidOperationException: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Registrar.Data.MultitenantIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser]'.
```

Stack trace shows all framework code and I am finding it difficult to figure out the **circular reference** .

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: it means that `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` has a dependency on a type that either directly depends on or has a dependency that depends on `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`.ie: `A => B, B => C, C => A`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. In the class;

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStoreMultiTenant<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>{}
```

I was requesting **UserManager** in the constructor which was causing the issue. It would have been nice if the framework shows at which line in my code made it to fail.

Comment: "It would have been nice if the framework shows at which line in my code made it to fail." If you are resolving a service directly from code, it is almost impossible for a DI Container to help you with this; the Service Locator anti-pattern blinds the DI Container from doing its job, which is one of the many reasons why Service Locator is called an anti-pattern.